# В чем суть "?=" в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение для пароля:

`/^[A-Z](?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*]{8,}/`

Его суть я понимаю.

1. (?=^[A-Z]) - первый символ пароля имеет верхний регистр
2. (?=.*[0-9]) - строка содержит хотя бы одно число;
3. (?=.*[!@#$%^&*]) - строка содержит хотя бы один спецсимвол;
4. (?=.*[a-z]) - строка содержит хотя бы одну латинскую букву в нижнем регистре;
5. (?=.*[A-Z]) - строка содержит хотя бы одну латинскую букву в верхнем регистре;
6. [0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*]{8,} - строка состоит не менее, чем из 8 вышеупомянутых символов.

Но не могу разобраться для чего тут `?=` и что оно означает.

Comment: Следует так же обратить внимание, что в регулярном выражение не хватает символа конца строки `$`, и если метод для проверки использует не полное совпадение строки, то использование может вызвать негативный эффект: https://regex101.com/r/hFCtYz/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знак вопроса `?` самостоятельно является квантификатором 0 или 1 совпадение предыдущего шаблона, а равно `=` не является метасимволом вовсе.

Только находясь в круглых скобках `(?=...)` они начинают работать как позитивный просмотр вперед.
Группа позитивного просмотра вперед отличается от обычной группы, тем что не захватывает данные, а устанавливает курсор:

Возьмем строку:
`abcd1f`
И регулярное выражение:
`.(?=[0-9])`
Точка в регулярных выражениях это любой символ(за некоторыми исключениями)

```txt
abcd1f
___^___ результатом захвата будет буква d перед цифрой 1
```

Если использовать обычную группу `.([0-9])`

```txt
abcd1f
___^^__ результатом захвата будет буква d и цифра 1
____^__ так же будет захвачена цифра 1 в группу 1
```

Как ранее уже говорили, что группы существуют нескольких типов:
`(?=...)` - позитивный просмотр вперед
`(?!...)` - негативный просмотр вперед
`(?<=...)` - позитивный просмотр назад
`(?<!...)` - негативный просмотр назад

на примере из работы:

```txt
fs4a
_^___ .(?=[0-9]) - захватит s
___^_ (?<=[0-9]). - захватит a
^_^^_ .(?![0-9]) - захватит f,4,a
^^^__ (?<![0-9]). - захватит f,s,4
```

Answer (score 8):

`?=` - это так называемое "заглядывание вперёд" (lookahead assertion).

Существует несколько типов такого "заглядывания":

1. Заглядывание вперед:  `foo(?=bar)`, совпадёт `foo` только перед `bar`, при этом сама строка `bar` не войдет в найденный текст.
2. Отрицательное заглядывание вперед: `foo(?!bar)`, совпадет `foo`, только если после этой строки не следует `bar`.
3. Ретроспективная проверка: `(?<=foo)bar`, совпадет `bar` только после `foo`, при этом сама строка `foo` не войдет в найденный текст.
4. Отрицательное заглядывание назад: `foo(?<!bar)`, совпадет `bar`, только если перед этой строкой нет `foo`.

[Источник примеров](https://regex.sorokin.engineer/ru/latest/regular_expressions.html)

Конкретно в вашем случае этот прием используется для того, чтобы объединить группы поиска отдельных частей пароля в одну общую сущность, предшествующая часть совпадёт, только в случае если после неё следует то, что указано после `?=`

Answer (score 1):

эта регулярка работает так:

- первая буква пароля - заглавная латинская
- она должна стоять перед цифрой (первое `(?=...)`)
- также она должна стоять перед символом из указанного списка (второе `(?=...)`)
- также она должна стоять перед малой латинской (третье `(?=...)`)
- также она должна стоять перед еще одной заглавной латинской (четвертое `(?=...)`)
- после нее должны стоять минимум восемь знаков из указанного списка

итого, пароль должен начинаться на заглавную латинскую букву и должен состоять не менее чем из 9 знаков, в том числе, цифр, малых и больших латинских и символов.